# Curved break modelling

Tags: modeling

I have a really hard time with modelling his object, can anyone help me? I would want to separate a beveled cube in half with this curved shape like in the example, but with the middle part being smooth.
Any ideas what is the easiet way to do that?

Thanks!

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by saying "the middle part being smooth"? The faces inbetween the gap should be shaded smooth? The contour of the gap should be smoother?

Comment: I mean the contournof the gap. Now you can see that it is fragmented